# How to get n number of value from array according to the weightage value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this in which around 300k entries.

```
var data = [
 {name: "peter", city: "bauru", weightage: 20},
 {name: "marcos", city: "belo", weightage: 15},
 {name: "rio", city: "salvador", weightage: 20},
 {name: "halter", city: "natal", weightage: 15},
 {name: "ron", city: "belem", weightage: 15},
 {name: "dominic", city: "santos", weightage: 15},
 {name: "john", city: "bauru", weightage: 20},
 {name: "ros", city: "natal", weightage: 15},
 {name: "nick", city: "salvador", weightage: 20},
 {name: "david", city: "santos", weightage: 15},
 {name: "ison", city: "belem", weightage: 15},
 {name: "eddy", city: "belo", weightage: 15},
....
 
]
```

I have entries in an array where every different user lie under these 6 cities. Every city have weightage value. So I have to random pick 60000 data according to the weightage value.

I tried to first segregate the data and pick 20% data from bauru, 15% from belo and so on but this manually do is not an good approach.

I don;t have any idea to write this on javascript.

***Expected output***:  I want 60k data in which 20% values is from bauru, 15% from belo, 20% from salvador, 15% from natal, 15% from belem and 15% from santos. Total count is 60k. If any city data 15% or 20% not comes on total then pick more data from 20% and 15%. Suppose 60k data of 15% = 7200 and any city total values is only 500 then we pick rest of the data from 20% or 15% from different city which have large amount of data

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: can you add som random data?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have added few more data. In this Only name of user is changed and also the city. You can say that its a list of users from few cities with count of 300k enteries. Out of that I want 60k data. Now that 60k data is the combination of weightage value

Answer (score 0):

You could group by city first and then pick the amount of items from the group.

```js
var data = [{ name: "peter", city: "bauru", weightage: 20 }, { name: "marcos", city: "belo", weightage: 15 }, { name: "rio", city: "salvador", weightage: 20 }, { name: "halter", city: "natal", weightage: 15 }, { name: "ron", city: "belem", weightage: 15 }, { name: "dominic", city: "santos", weightage: 15 }, { name: "john", city: "bauru", weightage: 20 }, { name: "ros", city: "natal", weightage: 15 }, { name: "nick", city: "salvador", weightage: 20 }, { name: "david", city: "santos", weightage: 15 }, { name: "ison", city: "belem", weightage: 15 }, { name: "eddy", city: "belo", weightage: 15 }, { name: "queen", city: "bauru", weightage: 20 }, { name: "lucia", city: "belo", weightage: 15 }, { name: "fran", city: "salvador", weightage: 20 }, { name: "yvonne", city: "natal", weightage: 15 }, { name: "audry", city: "belem", weightage: 15 }, { name: "gaby", city: "santos", weightage: 15 }, { name: "susan", city: "bauru", weightage: 20 }, { name: "tonya", city: "natal", weightage: 15 }, { name: "ines", city: "salvador", weightage: 20 }, { name: "karen", city: "santos", weightage: 15 }, { name: "petra", city: "belem", weightage: 15 }, { name: "jane", city: "belo", weightage: 15 }, { name: "jo", city: "bauru", weightage: 20 }, { name: "kim", city: "belo", weightage: 15 }, { name: "tony", city: "salvador", weightage: 20 }, { name: "adrian", city: "natal", weightage: 15 }, { name: "alex", city: "belem", weightage: 15 }, { name: "dana", city: "santos", weightage: 15 }, { name: "sam", city: "bauru", weightage: 20 }, { name: "nicola", city: "natal", weightage: 15 }, { name: "finn", city: "salvador", weightage: 20 }, { name: "sasha", city: "santos", weightage: 15 }, { name: "kay", city: "belem", weightage: 15 }, { name: "ira", city: "belo", weightage: 15 }],
    target = 20,
    groups = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.city]) r[o.city] = [];
        r[o.city].push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = Object.keys(groups).reduce((r, k) => {
        let count = Math.floor(target * groups[k][0].weightage/ 100);
        while (count-- && groups[k].length)
            r.push(groups[k].splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * groups[k].length), 1)[0]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution **groups all the data by city, randomizes the order of the records in each group, and takes the first X records from each group** where X is the total needed to achieve the desired weightage.

In the sample data, the totals are 3, 4, and 3, whereas in your real data, you would use 9000 for most cities (weightage 15) and 12 for the others (weightage 20).

(The last time I looked at your question, you hadn't yet added the specification that some cities might not have enough data to reach their desired weightage, so that situation is not handled, but I might be able to add something for that tomorrow if you still need help with it.)

```js
    // Creates the `cities` object and retrieves data
    const
      cities = getCities(),
      data = getData();

    // Copies all records from `data` into cities, grouped by city
    data.reduce( (acc, item) =>
      addRecordToCity(item, item.city), cities);

    // Randomizes and then truncates each city-specific array
    Object.keys(cities).forEach(city => {
      let
        cityData = cities[city].data,
        numberNeeded = cities[city].total;
      cities[city].data = shuffle(cityData).slice(0, numberNeeded);
    });

    // Prints results
    console.log("Selections:")
    Object.keys(cities).forEach(city => {
      cities[city].data.forEach(item =>
        console.log(item.name, item.city)
      );
    });


    // Coptes a record from `data` into `cities`, in the appropriate city
    function addRecordToCity(record, cityName){
      cities[cityName].data.push(record);
      return cities;
    }

    // Randomizes an array
    function shuffle(array){
      let i = array.length, rand, temp;
      while(--i > 0){
        rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * (i + 1) );
        temp = array[rand];
        array[rand] = array[i]
        array[i] = temp;
      }
      return array;
    }

    // Defines the cities object that will hold our final results
    function getCities(){
      return {  // Weightages are 30/40/30, collecting 10 records total
        "city_1": { total: 3, data: [] },
        "city_2": { total: 4, data: [] },
        "city_3": { total: 3, data: [] }
      };
    }

    // Defines source data
    function getData(){
      return [
        { name: "a", city: "city_1" },
        { name: "b", city: "city_2" },
        { name: "c", city: "city_3" },
        { name: "d", city: "city_1" },
        { name: "e", city: "city_2" },
        { name: "f", city: "city_3" },
        { name: "g", city: "city_1" },
        { name: "h", city: "city_2" },
        { name: "i", city: "city_3" },
        { name: "j", city: "city_1" },
        { name: "k", city: "city_2" },
        { name: "l", city: "city_3" },
        { name: "m", city: "city_1" },
        { name: "n", city: "city_2" },
        { name: "o", city: "city_3" },
        { name: "p", city: "city_1" },
        { name: "q", city: "city_2" },
        { name: "r", city: "city_3" }
      ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple if you create a control table which dictates how you want to select your samples.

I suggest a 2 step process. First filter your full record set down to only those records you deem 'valid' (i.e. have the correct city/age combinations) then you can pick and choose who you want in your final set:

```
var data = [
 {name: "peter", city: "bauru", weightage: 20},
 {name: "marcos", city: "belo", weightage: 15},
 {name: "rio", city: "salvador", weightage: 20},
 {name: "halter", city: "natal", weightage: 15},
 {name: "ron", city: "belem", weightage: 15},
 {name: "dominic", city: "santos", weightage: 15},
 {name: "john", city: "bauru", weightage: 20},
 {name: "ros", city: "natal", weightage: 15},
 {name: "nick", city: "salvador", weightage: 20},
 {name: "david", city: "santos", weightage: 15},
 {name: "ison", city: "belem", weightage: 15},
 {name: "eddy", city: "belo", weightage: 15}
]

//create a control array with the matches you want (city/weightage etc) 
//include the result percent you care about
let controlArray = [
  {city: "bauru", weightage: 20, resultPercent : .2},
  {city: "belo", weightage: 15, resultPercent : .2},
  {city: "salvador", weightage: 20, resultPercent : 0},
  {city: "natal", weightage: 15, resultPercent : .2},
  {city: "belem", weightage: 15, resultPercent : .2},
  {city: "santos", weightage: 15, resultPercent : .2}
];

//this is your result set
let validRecords = [];

//this is your sample size - I've used 5 as the sample data was only 12 rows
let requiredRecords = 5;

//iterate over the control array
controlArray.forEach(controlRecord => {
    //available records - here you filter out records that don't match your criteria
    let availablePeople = data.filter(individual => {return individual.city == controlRecord.city && individual.weightage == controlRecord.weightage});
  
    //get a sample from the reduced set
    let requiredNumberFromSet = Math.ceil(controlRecord.resultPercent*requiredRecords);

    validRecords = validRecords.concat(availablePeople.slice(0, requiredNumberFromSet));
});

//your result set, here you should see five records - one from each city excluding salvador which I set to 0% for this demo.
console.log(validRecords);
```

You can also add 'overflow' logic in this approach fairly easily if one set doesn't have enough valid matches you can store that as a variable and add it to the selection in the next control row.